# White color and yellow color is almost the same on my monitor, what can I do being on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, graphics, display, colors

I have an old monitor. On Windows, we have Intel or Asus (or you name it) settings for a graphics card that allow configuring color curve. I see that I can install some custom color profile but how can I make it without compiling some ICC editing tools by myself?

UPD:
I couldn't calibrate because of the [**disabled** "Сalibrate..." button](http://savephoto.ru/f/10nb4qazj2tr12)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/color-calibrate-screen.html.en
except you'll need to create the color profile for your monitor.

EDIT: to make the calibrate button enabled you need to have some calibration device called spectrometer (eyes cannot be trusted).
Such device can be bought on ebay, called "colorhug" and originates from:
https://hughski.com/index.html. of course there are some more expensive alternatives.

for manual profile creation you can use:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/lprof.1.html

but I suggest downloading the official profile from the display vendor (if available)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't because my **Calibrate...** button is disabled, I've attached the screenshot

Comment: updated my answer